# Why can't I send "keys" to oclHashcat process started from java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I have a simple Java program that starts a oclHashcat (actually cudaHashcat) process and tries to communicate with the started process.
Reading of output from the process works fine however I can't seem to write to the process.

Demo code that shows what I'm trying to do: (Pressing s in the program is supposed to show a status of the current operation, however nothing happens

```
public class CudaHashcat {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cudaHashcat64.exe", "-m", "0", "-b");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE);
    builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
    final Process process = builder.start();
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Writing to hashcat process"); // this shows up just fine
                process.getOutputStream().write('s');
                process.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it's only `s` and not `s` followed by a newline? `.write()` will not write the newline for you

Comment: Yes I am, on the commandline simply pressing "s" does the trick. Also writing a "\n" after the s does not change the behaviour

Comment: OK, then are you sure the process acutally listens on stdin? Doesn't it check that stdin is a "tty" of some sort and not accepting inputs in this case? I don't know how to tell that on Windows though

Comment: I am not sure of that. It would make sense that the program checks for a tty (there is a Linux version of oclHashcat, can I check on that what is going on?). Then my question probably needs to be "can I make my Java program look like a tty to the started process to send keys to it".